# What is the practice of using elaborate introductions to one's idea called?

Tags: speech

The following is an exaggerated example:

Suppose that three people wanted to express their opinions of StackExchange:

> **Person A:** StackExchange is cool
>
> **Person B:** I think that StackExchange is cool
>
> **Person C:** I have a feeling that I would like to almost allow myself to think that StackExchange is cool

What is the speech pattern of **Person C** called?

Comment: A lengthy *introduction* which might be: *“Ladies and gentlemen before I actually say whether I believe SE is cool or not, I would like to say a little something about myself...bla...bla...”* That would be a tiresome  [**preamble**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/preamble).

Comment: There are so many single-word-requests for this type of question, I'm surprised nobody has pointed out any.... [Is there a word similar to Verbatim that means “Too many meaningless words used”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/256824/is-there-a-word-similar-to-verbatim-that-means-too-many-meaningless-words-used); and [Word to describe “when someone describes something in too much detail”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94774/word-to-describe-when-someone-describes-something-in-too-much-detail/94781#94781)

Comment: Then there's [Is there a word for a person who gives out too many extraneous details?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15940/is-there-a-word-for-a-person-who-gives-out-too-many-extraneous-details) and [Word for a person who talks without content](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/242760/word-for-a-person-who-talks-without-content) etc. etc.

Comment: *What is the speech pattern of Person C called?*  Self-absorbed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a example of [verbiage](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/verbiage):

> - an excess of words for the purpose; wordiness.(AHD)
> - the excessive and often meaningless use of words; verbosity. (Collins)